# Using a lambda expression with match

Tags: f#

I am trying to use a lambda expression to help me return a value but I am getting an error that says

> the function takes too many agruments, or is used in a context where a
>   function is not expected

.

Here is the sample code:

```
match isTrue with
| true -> 1
| false -> (fun () -> 2) //<----Error
```

So is it not possible to use a lambda expression here, or am I missing something?

Comment: Main problem here is that `1` is an `int` and the function is not.  But probably something else as well, which is in the missing code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Being new to F#, I assumed that:

```
(fun () -> 2)
```

would automatically execute in the match expression. I just simply need to write the code needed as in

```
match isTrue with
| true -> 1
| false -> 
    let something = 48 + 3
    something + 4
```

Comment: `(fun () -> 2)` only define a function with no argument which **when called** will return 2 ; you can certainly do `(fun () -> 2) ()` that is calling the function right after it's definition but in that case why not returning 2 in the first place ?

Comment: The actual code is a bit more detailed than simply returning an int.  Your explanation about the missing unit as an argument is helpful though. Thanks.

Comment: Even if it's more than just an int ; i still don't see the point in calling a just created anonymous function vs just doing the current body (whatever it is) of that called anonymous function ?

Comment: I don't see the point either; now that I realize I can just simply write out the required code. Being new to F#, for whatever reason, I assumed that I had to package multiple lines of code into a function in regards to using it with a match statement.  Probably just a hangover coming from C# and LINQ.